# Создание кастомных сервлетов во время работы

Tags: java

Работаю над одним проектом и появился вопрос: мне нужно что бы во время приложения, к примеру после нажатия кнопки, создавалась новая страничка с кастомной url, но я не знаю как это сделать. Использую Java EE и Tomcat)

Если кто не понял, вот примерный сценарий:
Пользователь ввёл текст (к примеру "test-page") -> нажал на кнопку -> создалась страница с адресом "localhost/test-page"

Comment: а контент страницы тоже юзверь может сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно создавать кастомный сервлет. Вам нужен один сервлет, который ловит все URL, разбирает path и понимает какую страницу отобразить, вернее какой контент отдать клиенту. На клиенте у Вас будет SPA (Single Page Application), которое будет отображать тот или иной контент, опять же в зависимости от URL. Так функционируют большинство известных CMS/CMF.

Comment: Немного не понимаю как это реализовать...

Comment: @НикитаИвченко, чтобы это понять, надо разобраться как сейчас у вас происходит маппинг URL на Ваши сервлеты

Comment: Вообщем пришёл к решению в файле web.xml создать сервлет и перенаправлять на него все ссылки с адресом "localhost/custom-link/*", спасибо за подсказку